# python equivalent to perl's qw()

Tags: python, perl, quotes

I do this a lot in Perl:

```
printf "%8s %8s %8s\n", qw(date price ret);
```

However, the best I can come up with in Python is

```
print '%8s %8s %8s' % (tuple("date price ret".split()))
```

I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it? I'm fine if you tell me that's it and no improvement can be made.

Comment: Why is this a community wiki?  That "feature" really needs to be removed.

Comment: Sorry, I must have mis-clicked the wiki box. How do I remove it? (Don't see such option when I try to edit.) What exactly should be posted to community wiki anyways? thx.

Comment: It can't be removed, just consider this a lesson for next time. The idea behind the community wiki option is probably best explained at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: The `tuple()` and the extra parens are redundant. That's why @masonk wrote their answer, i.e., just do `print '%8s %8s %8s' % "date price ret".split()`.

Comment: not a complete answer; but you know source code doesn't have to be "typed" by a human? it can be made by a perl 1line script...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, there's definitely no way to do exactly what you can do in Perl, because Python will complain about undefined variable names and a syntax error (missing comma, perhaps). But I would write it like this (in Python 2.X):

```
print '%8s %8s %8s' % ('date', 'price', 'ret')
```

If you're really attached to Perl's syntax, I guess you could define a function `qw` like this:

```
def qw(s):
    return tuple(s.split())
```

and then you could write

```
print '%8s %8s %8s' % qw('date price ret')
```

which is basically Perl-like except for the one pair of quotes on the argument to `qw`. But I'd hesitate to recommend that. At least, don't do it only because you miss Perl - it only enables your denial that you're working in a new programming language now ;-) It's like the old story about Pascal programmers who switch to C and create macros

```
#define BEGIN {
#define END   }
```

Comment: To be sure, I was explicitly trying to get around typing quotes around each word. The word list usually runs in the neighborhood of 15-20, hence the need for qw() in the first place.

Comment: Well, I think the usual Python way to do it is just suck it up and type the quotes - after all, you only have to do it once. But I don't suppose there's anything really _wrong_ with using this `qw` function. It might confuse anyone who reads your source code who isn't familiar with Perl, but if you can live with that, go right ahead.

Comment: "after all, you only have to do it once" - except that you only have to do it once, every time that you have to do it.  Before I started coding in perl regularly I never realized how frequently I created arrays of single tokens, or hashes with single tokens for the keys (which is another opportunity to omit quotes in perl).  The "qw" isn't significant, it's just nice to have a common case optimization that enables you to remove the quotes.

Comment: The Blub Paradox is real.  :)  http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html  (Found this in my hunt for the equivalent in other languages.  At least ruby has it (`%w`).)

Answer (score 13):

`"date price ret".split()`

Comment: That's what the OP already suggested. Not really helpful therefore.

Answer (score 3):

`QW()` is often used to print column headings using `join()` in Perl.  Column heads in the real-world are sometimes long -- making `join("\t", qw())` very useful because it's easier to read and helps to eliminate typos (e.g. `"x","y"` or `"x\ty"`).  Below is a related approach in real-world Python:

```
    print("\t".join('''PubChemId Column ESImode Library.mzmed
      Library.rtmed Metabolite newID Feature.mzmed Feature.rtmed
      Count ppmDiff rtDiff'''.split()))
```

The triple quote string is a weird thing because it doubles as a comment.  In this context, however, it is a string and it frees us from having to worry about line breaks (as `qw()` would).

Thanks to the previous replies for reveling this approach.