# Unpythonic way of printing variables in Python?

Tags: python

Someone has recently demonstrated to me that we can print variables in Python like how Perl does.

Instead of:

```
print("%s, %s, %s" % (foo, bar, baz))
```

we could do:

```
print("%(foo)s, %(bar)s, %(baz)s" % locals())
```

Is there a less hacky looking way of printing variables in Python like we do in Perl? I think the 2nd solution actually looks really good and makes code a lot more readable, but the locals() hanging around there makes it look like such a convoluted way of doing it.

Comment: This looks awfully close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534714/python-equivalent-to-perls-qw ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550479 (no endorsement of the answers, which I havn't read)

Comment: You've said, essentially, that you want Python to be more like Perl. Which aspect of Perl? There's more than one way to format a string.

Comment: Just the part where we can format a string by referencing variables directly in the quotes, rather than having to format it outside of the quotes. I just find that strings are a lot more readable when you don't have to read outside the quotes. No break in flow (can't think of a better way to describe it.. urgh)

Comment: @Greg: What are you talking about?  He said exactly what he wants.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: Perl has at least: (a) sprintf, (b) string interpolation, and (c) concatenation. I didn't think it was obvious at first glance which one Chien is looking for. A Perl example would have made it completely clear.

Comment: @Greg: Seems clear enough: using `"%(foo)s, %(bar)s, %(baz)s"` like `"$foo, $bar, $baz`.  *shrug*

Comment: @Chien: When you want to print variables it's time to start a debugger. PyDev has one *everyone* can use right away.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15013982/490829 (shameless promotion)

Comment: I'm endorsing the great answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550479/python-is-using-vars-locals-a-good-practice/1551187#1551187 for why this is a bad idea. Quoting the Zen of Python: `Explicit is better than implicit.` /cc @GlennMaynard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only other way would be to use the Python 2.6+/3.x [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) method for string formatting:

```
# dict must be passed by reference to .format()
print("{foo}, {bar}, {baz}").format(**locals())
```

Or referencing specific variables by name:

```
# Python 2.6
print("{0}, {1}, {2}").format(foo, bar, baz) 

# Python 2.7/3.1+
print("{}, {}, {}").format(foo, bar, baz)
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly make it look cleaner.

Comment: Just added the specific ones for when referencing the variable directly. The 2.7/3.1+ version is definitely the cleanest of them all in my opinion.

Comment: Fine, right up until you start pulling the strings from a localization database. At that point, you have to go back to using explicit orderings because different languages prefer different orders of values. (Really.)

Comment: you can use `vars()` instead of `locals()`. Also `vars(obj)` to use `obj.__dict__` for the substitutions

Answer (score 5):

Using `% locals()` or `.format(**locals())` is not always a good idea. As example, it could be a possible security risk if the string is pulled from a localization database or could contain user input, and it mixes program logic and translation, as you will have to take care of the strings used in the program.

A good workaround is to limit the strings available. As example, I have a program that keeps some informations about a file. All data entities have a dictionary like this one:

```
myfile.info = {'name': "My Verbose File Name", 
               'source': "My Verbose File Source" }
```

Then, when the files are processes, I can do something like this:

```
for current_file in files:
    print 'Processing "{name}" (from: {source}) ...'.format(**currentfile.info)
    # ...
```

Comment: +1 This is a good point. Don't know why someone would downvote it.

Comment: Yep, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550479/python-is-using-vars-locals-a-good-practice/1551187#1551187 for a thorough discussion on why `Explicit is better than implicit.` in exactly this context.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the `.format()` method myself, but you can always do:

```
age = 99
name = "bobby"
print name, "is", age, "years old"
```

Produces: `bobby is 99 years old`. Notice the implicit spaces.

Or, you can get real nasty:

```
def p(*args):
    print "".join(str(x) for x in args))

p(name, " is ", age, " years old")
```

Comment: Why would you do that? (The nasty part)

Comment: @sharvey, the question is asking for unpythonic.

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.6, you could have what you wanted.

```
>>> name = "world"
>>> print(f'hello {name}')
hello world
```

note the string prefix `f` above

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, no, the syntax for strings in Python does not include variable substitution inthe style of Perl (or Ruby, for that matter). Using `… % locals()` is about as slick as you are going to get.