# Using Python Variables in HTML in multiline Python string

Tags: python, html

I´m trying to write HTML code using python and execute it from browser. Here is my code:

```
import webbrowser

f = open('image.html','w')

message = """<html>
<head></head>
<body><img src="URL"></body>
</html>"""

f.write(message)
f.close()

filename = 'file:///home/pi/' + 'image.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)
```

Simple code, works like a charm!

Now I want to make little ¨UI¨, so that user will be able to input the URL. So my question is, can I put Python Variable into the HTML code instead of URL?
for example:

```
a = ¨webpage.com/image.jpg¨
...
<img src="a">
...
```

For sure, I know that the syntax is super wrong, I just wanted to give you an example of what I´m trying to achieve.
cheers!

Comment: String formatting sounds like a topic that would be useful for you to read up on: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using python 3.6+, you can use [formatted strings literals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
>>> URL = "http://path.to/image.jpg"
>>> message = f"""<html>
... <head></head>
... <body><img src="{URL}"></body>
... </html>"""
>>> print(message)
<html>
<head></head>
<body><img src="http://path.to/image.jpg"></body>
</html>
>>>
```

If you are using python 2.7+ you can use `string.format()`:

```
>>> URL = "http://path.to/image.jpg"
>>> message = """<html>
... <head></head>
... <body><img src="{}"></body>
... </html>"""
>>> print(message.format(URL))
<html>
<head></head>
<body><img src="http://path.to/image.jpg"></body>
</html>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into **variable interpolation** (or more generally, **string formatting**). Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542749/5684441). To give you a quick example:

```
foo = "hello"
bar = """world
%s""" % foo

print bar
```

...will output...

```
hello
world
```