# How can I interpolate variables in Python heredocs?

Tags: python, heredoc, string-interpolation

In Perl languages, I can interpolate in double quoted heredocs:

Perl:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $job  = 'foo';
my $cpus = 3;

my $heredoc = <<"END";
#SBATCH job $job
#SBATCH cpus-per-task $cpus
END

print $heredoc;
```

Raku (F.K.A. Perl 6):

```
#!/bin/env perl6

my $job  = 'foo';
my $cpus = 3;

my $heredoc = qq:to/END/;
    #SBATCH job $job
    #SBATCH cpus-per-task $cpus
    END

print $heredoc;
```

How do I do something similar in Python? In searching "heredoc string interpolation Python", I did come across information on Python f-strings, which facilitate string interpolation (for Python 3.6 and later).

Python 3.6+ with f-strings:

```
#!/bin/env python3

job  = 'foo'
cpus = 3
print(f"#SBATCH job {job}")
print(f"#SBATCH cpus-per-task {cpus}")
```

All three of the above produce the exact same output:

> ```
> #SBATCH job cutadapt
> #SBATCH cpus-per-task 3
> ```

That's all nice and everything, but I'm still really interested in interpolation in ***heredocs*** using Python.

Comment: Note, since this specifically deals with heredocs, this is different from the many easy-to-find questions that deal with variable interpolation in Python strings (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542714/variable-interpolation-in-python).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just for the record, the other string formatting options in Python also work for multi-line tripple-quoted strings:

```
a = 42
b = 23

s1 = """
some {} foo
with {}
""".format(a, b)

print(s1)

s2 = """
some %s foo
with %s
""" % (a, b)

print(s2)
```

Comment: Awesome! And those will work for versions of Python before 3.6.

Answer (score 12):

What in many languages are known as "heredocs" are typically called "triple-quoted strings" in Python. You simply need to create a [triple-quoted f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#triple-quoted-f-strings):

```
#!/bin/env python3

cpus = 3
job  = 'foo'
print(f'''\
#SBATCH job {job}
#SBATCH cpus-per-task {cpus}''')
```

As you previously noted, however, this is specific to Python 3.6 and later.

---

If you want to do more than just interpolate variables, f-strings also provide evaluation of code inside curly braces:

```
#!/bin/env python3
print(f'5+7 = {5 + 7}')
```

> ```
> 5+7 = 12
> ```

This is very similar to double quoted strings in Raku (F.K.A. Perl 6):

```
#!/bin/env perl6
put "5+7 = {5 + 7}";
```

> ```
> 5+7 = 12
> ```