# Something better than locals() or dict(foo=foo) for exporting context to template engines

Tags: python, django, jinja2

So, after a brief discussion on #python about [why not to use locals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1551187/490829), I was pondering about what would be a better way without the repetitive nature (i.e. not DRY) of `dict(foo=foo,bar=bar)` (or the same using the literal syntax (`{}`)).

Ideally, a PEP could be submitted (or one already exists) that mirrors [this ecmascript harmony proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:object_initialiser_shorthand). (I want to promote emphasis on the DRY aspect that it conveys).

So, do you have any solutions? Should I submit a PEP?

Comment: Good question - although, not properly suitable for Stack Overflow as this is really an invitation to a discussion.  This would do better on the Python mailing lists.

Comment: And, less I be remiss - here is the info about the available [Python mailing lists](http://python.org/community/lists/).

Comment: Yeah, SO's just a little more accessible as far as web content goes -- you don't have to fumble through the archives just to find the answer when the search result comes up. Thanks, I'll definitely ask this on the mailinglist.

Comment: @forivall I'd be curious what came of the discussion if you took this to the mailing lists. Any links?

Comment: @RyneEverett Never did. Sorry. I'm working mostly with nodejs these days anyways, so I don't have much motivation to try again.

Comment: Sigh. pep-0498 doesn't solve this.... on second though, it might be doable with a hack :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My currently proposed solution to this is the following pattern. Please tell me if this is just as bad of a practice as using `locals()`.

```
class _Context:
    foo = 'bar'
render(request, 'example.html', vars(_Context))
```

One caveat is that this might be a little iffy with python3 because it will use new-style classes with an immutable `dictproxy`, and I'd need to see how it would interact with the given templating library. Works fine with a simple `'{foo}'.format(**_Context.__dict__)`.

It *is* a definite improvement over `locals()`, since it's fairly explicit, and it doesn't leak other parts of the local scope. However, it does leak `'__module__'` and `'__doc__'` with old style classes and a bunch of other stuff with new-style classes.

Comment: This, or `__dict__` is fine! Asked to someone more pythonic than me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. There might be better ways to structure this, but it works!

Setup (Python 2 and 3):

```
class ContextDictBase(type):
    @staticmethod
    def __newnew(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs.pop('__module__', None)
        return attrs
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        ContextDictBase.__new__ = staticmethod(ContextDictBase.__newnew)
        return super(ContextDictBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

Python 2:

```
class ContextDict(object):
    __metaclass__ = ContextDictBase
```

Python 3:

```
class ContextDict(object, metaclass=ContextDictBase):
    pass
```

And then to use it:

```
class context(ContextDict):
    a = 1
    b = 2

>>> context
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

And a variation on the metaclass/attrs solution:

```
def make_dict(name, bases, attrs):
    attrs.pop('__module__')
    attrs.pop('__metaclass__', None)  # not needed in python3
    return attrs
```

Python 2:

```
class Context:
    __metaclass__ = make_dict
```

Python 3:

```
class Context(metaclass=make_dict):
    a = 1
    b = 2
```

Really, this question has just turned into my sandbox for playing with metaclasses