# Perl qw-operator in Python?

Tags: python, list, operators, quotes

I'm a native perl but are using python a lot lately. I was wondering if there is something similar to the perl qw// operator which is a shortcut to get around typing multiple quotes and commas when creating a list of several strings that do not include spaces.

Example: `@list = qw(Paul Michael Jessica Megan);` (from [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_Programming/Array_Variables)

I can't really find anything but the operator's name might be very different...
Cheers, Lars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python equivalent to perl's qw()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534714/python-equivalent-to-perls-qw)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but you could use `split`:

```
my_list = "Paul Michael Jessica Megan".split(" ")
```

Comment: You can omit the space argument as it splits on any whitespace by default.

Comment: True. I was just curious if there was something alike. But these kind of solutions are damn handy about python, I have to admit.